# GCD Scrollview loading issue

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, grand-central-dispatch

I'm using GCD to load images for my scroll view but rather than following the frames i created it makes only a single frame in which the images just flicker through. Here's my code:

```
//Create the array    
-(void)awakeFromNib {

images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"imageOne" ofType:@"png"]], [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"imageTwo" ofType:@"png"]], [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"imageThree" ofType:@"png"]],nil];

}

 //Populate scrollview
-(void)populate {

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);


scrollview.pagingEnabled = YES;
scrollview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
scrollview.clipsToBounds = YES;
scrollview.delegate = self;

[scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(2 * scrollview.frame.size.width, scrollview.frame.size.height)];

int number = [images count] ;
NSLog(@"%i",images);

int rowTwoInt = 0;
int rowThreeInt = 0;
int rowFourInt = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {



    if (i <= 3) {

        finalFrame = CGRectMake( i*(80), 12, 80, 80);
    }

    if (i == 4) {
        finalFrame = CGRectMake(0, 95, 80, 80);
    }
    if ((i >4) && (i <= 7)) {
        rowTwoInt = rowTwoInt + 80;
        finalFrame = CGRectMake(rowTwoInt, 95, 80, 80);
    }

    if (i == 8) {
         finalFrame = CGRectMake(0, 178, 80, 80);
    }
    if ((i > 8) && (i <= 11)) {
        rowThreeInt = rowThreeInt + 80;
        finalFrame = CGRectMake(rowThreeInt, 178, 80, 80);
    }


    if (i == 12) {
        finalFrame = CGRectMake(0, 261, 80, 80);
    }
    if ((i > 12) && (i <= 15)) {
        rowFourInt = rowFourInt + 80;
        finalFrame = CGRectMake(rowFourInt, 261, 80, 80);
    }


    IconButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    IconButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 57, 57);
    IconButton.center = CGPointMake(40, 29);

    [IconButton addTarget:self action:@selector(Selected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    IconButton.tag = i;



    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        UIImage *icon = [images objectAtIndex:i];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [IconButton setImage:icon forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        });
    });



    [cell addSubview:IconButton];


      cell = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:finalFrame];
 [scrollview addSubview:cell];
```

So what am i doing wrong? I'm new with GCD so it's probably something with that. Also if you see a way to improve UIScrollView performance, please let me know.

Comment: Please fix your code to be properly indented.  Also, show us how `IconButton` is declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you have declared `IconButton` as an instance variable, a `static` variable, or a global variable.

Each time through your loop, you change the value of `IconButton`.  By the time your twelve queue blocks execute, `IconButton` is set to its final value - a reference to the last button you created.  All the blocks use the instance (or `static` or global) `IconButton` variable, so all the blocks update the same, final button.

Make a local variable to reference the button, and use that local variable in the loop:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
IconButton = button;
IconButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 57, 57);
...

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    UIImage *icon = [images objectAtIndex:i];

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [button setImage:icon forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    });
});
```

Each block will capture the value of the local variable at the moment the block is created, so each block will capture a reference to a different button.